# document.getElementById("box5"&&"box14") getting only the second argument

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that sets the variable `trouve_coupable` to `true` if both `box 5` and `box 14` have been checked on the HTML page. But whatever I may do on the page, as long as `box 14` (`="case14"`) is `checked`, it returns `true` but it should be `false`.

(Sorry for my program being in French)

```
function verifier() {
    if (document.getElementById("case5"&&"case14").checked) {
        trouve_coupable = true;
    }
    else {
        trouve_coupable = false;
    }

    if (trouve_coupable){
        window.location="lieu16.html" 
    }
    else {
        alert("Incorrect! Faîtes plus attention aux détails qui vous entourent et prenez des notes!!");
        window.location="lieu17r.html" 
    }
}
```

And here's the HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Poursuite dans la forêt</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script src="script.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Quel est le mot de passe?</h1>
      Le nombre (Tous les indices ensembles)<br>
      <input type="radio" name="coupable" id="case1" />01246
      <input type="radio" name="coupable"  id="case2" />10264
      <input type="radio" name="coupable"  id="case3" />46201
      <input type="radio" name="coupable"  id="case4" />26410
      <input type="radio" name="coupable"  id="case5" />62140
      <input type="radio" name="coupable"  id="case6" />41260
      <br/>
      Le mot<br>
      <input type="radio" name="mobile" id="case7" />Hamburger
      <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case8" />Pringles
      <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case9" />Faygo
      <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case10" />Jambon cru
      <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case11" />Jambon cuit
      <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case12" />Jambon fumé
      <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case13" />Jambon de Bayonne
      <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case14" />Jambon
      <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case15" />Jambon Serrano
      <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case16" />Jambon Ibérique
      <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case17" />Jambon Bodega
      <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case18" />Lardons
      <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case19" />Bacon
      <br/>
      <input type="button" value = "Envoyer" onclick="verifier()">
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: JavaScript is not a natural language. While that statement might sound logically, for JavaScript it makes no sense. (At least not in the way you meant it.) First get the first element and its checked value, then do the same for the second element then use `&&` on those boolean values.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you so much ! I did this and now it works perfectly :

var a = (document.getElementById("case5").checked)
 var b = (document.getElementById("case14").checked)
 var c = a&&b
 if(c == true){
  trouve_coupable = true;

Comment: `const trouve_coupable = document.getElementById("case5").checked && document.getElementById("case14").checked;`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass a formula to `getElementById` but it should receive the id of one element. What you want is to evaluate a formula with the results of the property checked.
When you do `a && b` in javascript it is equivalent to `a ? a : b`, thus your id "case5" && "case14" is a constant expression returning case14. Fixing this, here is what you have.

```js
function verifier() {
if (document.getElementById("case5").checked && 
     document.getElementById("case14").checked) {
    trouve_coupable = true;
}
else {
    trouve_coupable = false;
}
if (trouve_coupable){
    // window.location="lieu16.html" 
    alert("bon travail!")
}
else {
    alert("Incorrect! Faîtes plus attention aux détails qui vous entourent et prenez des notes!!");
    // window.location="lieu17r.html" 
}
}
```

```html
<h1>Quel est le mot de passe?</h1>
  Le nombre (Tous les indices ensembles)<br>
  <input type="radio" name="coupable" id="case1" />01246
  <input type="radio" name="coupable"  id="case2" />10264
  <input type="radio" name="coupable"  id="case3" />46201
  <input type="radio" name="coupable"  id="case4" />26410
  <input type="radio" name="coupable"  id="case5" />62140
  <input type="radio" name="coupable"  id="case6" />41260
  <br/>
  Le mot<br>
  <input type="radio" name="mobile" id="case7" />Hamburger
  <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case8" />Pringles
  <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case9" />Faygo
  <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case10" />Jambon cru
  <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case11" />Jambon cuit
  <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case12" />Jambon fumé
  <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case13" />Jambon de Bayonne
  <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case14" />Jambon
  <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case15" />Jambon Serrano
  <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case16" />Jambon Ibérique
  <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case17" />Jambon Bodega
  <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case18" />Lardons
  <input type="radio" name="mobile"  id="case19" />Bacon
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value = "Envoyer" onclick="verifier()">
```

Comment: So, please mark indicate this https://stackoverflow.com/tour, it will guide other users in the future, avoid others to waste time writing more answers, and increase my reputation as well :D. Thank you

Comment: im not the person asking the question lol.. but i did upvote

Comment: heheh I din't realise.